# Sum variable and keep showing and updating it

Tags: php, javascript

I have this function, that it's part of my game, and which sends the data to the getScore.php. And in that php I have some code that sends me back the score for every tag that the player enter, like this "100" "50" or "10.
Now I want to grab those scores and sum them and keep showing the player his score (updating), until the game is over.

```
function showScore() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "getScore.php",
        data:{
            tag: $("#tag").val(),
            timecode: curTime,
            filename: getFileName(),
            gameid: gameID()
        }
    }).done(function( msg )
    {
    show3(msg);

    });

    return false; 
};
```

The last function is where I show the score, but now I want to change it for sum and show.
How can I do this?!

```
var score;

function show3(string)
{
document.getElementById('myScore').innerHTML = string;
return string;
}
```

Comment: What's `function( msg )`? It looks odd to me.

Comment: It's to grab my "printf ($score);" from the php file!

Comment: @TinaCGHoehr - That's an anonymous function, no worries. It passes a function to the `done` callback that's executed when that's called.

Comment: @TinaCGHoehr what is odd about it?

Comment: Now that Jared explained, nothing is wrong, I suppose. Just trying to figure out how to best solve the OP's question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm guessing you want to add the score you get from myScore.php to `score` and display it. The `parseInt()` function should do the trick:

```
function show3(msg)
{
score = score+parseInt(msg);
document.getElementById('myScore').innerHTML = score;
return score;
}
```

firstly, naming the var and the function parameter `score` is confusing you. Secondly,you weren't adding the score you got from getScore.php you're replacing it.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I think something is wrong. Instead of the increasing score, I'm getting this message "NaN" when score is showed...

Comment: put `alert(msg)` at the top of the function to see the data being sent back. The value is only NaN(Not a Number) if `msg` has characters other than numbers(and a few more like 'x' and '.'). Your php script is probably returning an error

Comment: either than or u didnt initialize score to zero. do this `var score = 0;`

Comment: After some changes, it doesn't work the way I want, because instead of summing it, it replace the score.
What i think i need to do is another function that should be called before showing it. Because every time I enter a tag, I will always go to the function showScore().

Comment: The function in this answer does the summing when it does `score = score+parseInt(msg);`.

Comment: in the second code snippet you have `var score;`, change it to `var score=0;`. thats wat i meant

Comment: why would you want to do this: `string = string+parseInt(string);` by the way? lets say your php code returned 10 and you called the show3 function. `string` is now a string "10", since u passed 10 to the function, thus string+parseInt(string) would be "10"+parseInt("10") which is just concatenating the number 10 to a string "10" which makes it "1010".

Comment: You're right. I'm not thinking well at 4.30AM, and so I did those mistakes. I just woke up, and tried it again, and everything is fine, and just the way I want :) Thank you.